# Application crash on waking app from idle

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiview

My app is crashing when I wake it up from idle after long time. This is not always reproducible but it happens every third or fourth time. In my viewWillAppear I am calling some methods on self object.

The crash log says:

```
Incident Identifier: E009C90F-E544-4E2F-9A32-A5F630447510
CrashReporter Key:   32cf5a93f8d9560a1180daaf7c03328648745970
Hardware Model:      iPod4,1
Process:         SampleApp [4350]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/0D638C5B-E187-4F3B-8201-3EEA7B19D009/SampleApp.app/SampleApp
Identifier:      SampleApp
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-06-17 06:41:13.754 +0000
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.2.1 (8C148)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00000011
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x33a06464 objc_msgSend + 16
1   UIKit                           0x3164fdb2 -[UIAlertView(Private) _popoutAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 322
2   UIKit                           0x313ae330 -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 184
3   UIKit                           0x313bac0e -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 34
4   QuartzCore                      0x32d96ea2 run_animation_callbacks(double, void*) + 286
5   QuartzCore                      0x32d96d44 CA::timer_callback(__CFRunLoopTimer*, void*) + 116
6   CoreFoundation                  0x3044509c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 8
7   CoreFoundation                  0x30444b54 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 844
8   CoreFoundation                  0x304161ae __CFRunLoopRun + 1082
9   CoreFoundation                  0x30415c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
10  CoreFoundation                  0x30415b88 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
11  GraphicsServices                0x31eec4a4 GSEventRunModal + 108
12  GraphicsServices                0x31eec550 GSEventRun + 56
13  UIKit                           0x313cf322 -[UIApplication _run] + 406
14  UIKit                           0x313cce8c UIApplicationMain + 664
15  SampleApp                           0x000020cc 0x1000 + 4300
16  SampleApp                           0x0000208c 0x1000 + 4236

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x310bf974 kevent + 24
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31169704 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 88
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31169174 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 96
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31168b98 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 120
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3110d24a _pthread_wqthread + 258
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31105970 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31093268 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31095354 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x30416648 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x30415ed2 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x30415c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x30415b88 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   WebCore                         0x35b32124 RunWebThread(void*) + 332
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3110c886 _pthread_start + 242
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31101a88 thread_start + 0

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31093268 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31095354 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x30416648 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x30415ed2 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x30415c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x30415b88 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   Foundation                      0x302fb5f6 +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 206
7   Foundation                      0x302d9192 -[NSThread main] + 38
8   Foundation                      0x302d2242 __NSThread__main__ + 966
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3110c886 _pthread_start + 242
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x31101a88 thread_start + 0

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x310b768c select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x3044d662 __CFSocketManager + 582
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3110c886 _pthread_start + 242
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31101a88 thread_start + 0

Thread 5:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3110d9e0 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3110d364 _pthread_wqthread + 540
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x31105970 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x0079fed0    r1: 0x316aaf3a      r2: 0x007d8660      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0x00000009    r5: 0x3e36d7b0      r6: 0x00795980      r7: 0x2fdfeae0
    r8: 0x00000001    r9: 0x2fdfea44     r10: 0x007d8660     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x3e2cec58    sp: 0x2fdfeaa8      lr: 0x3164fdb9      pc: 0x33a06464
  cpsr: 0x00070030

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -   0x1c5fff +SampleApp armv7  <8f6fc1ff01643d73af62d09f8faa1b87> /var/mobile/Applications/0D638C5B-E187-4F3B-8201-3EEA7B19D009/SampleApp.app/SampleApp
  0x860000 -   0x861fff  dns.so armv7  <fcefecb2d5e095ba88127eec3af57ec0> /usr/lib/info/dns.so
  0x864000 -   0x868fff  AccessibilitySettingsLoader armv7  <e29064e428ed8f88cea9e057b5f2bb45> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/AccessibilitySettingsLoader.bundle/AccessibilitySettingsLoader
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe27fff  dyld armv7  <06e6959cebb4a72e66c833e26ae64d26> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30040000 - 0x30043fff  ActorKit armv7  <f5d038591e564646e9237a59c6c14293> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x30044000 - 0x30047fff  ApplePushService armv7  <9d1eb7b11f0f146c941efbab2c055606> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x30048000 - 0x30088fff  CoreAudio armv7  <f32e03ee4c68f0db23f05afc9a3cc94c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x30089000 - 0x30092fff  ITSync armv7  <87d409553f90e41a01afce047dc2e8fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ITSync.framework/ITSync
0x30093000 - 0x30093fff  vecLib armv7  <e53d234e808c77d286161095f92c58cf> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x30094000 - 0x30095fff  DataMigration armv7  <babbc72d4d48325de147d5103d7bc00d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x300aa000 - 0x301cafff  CoreGraphics armv7  <2d7b40a7baca915ce78b1dd9a0d6433b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x3020c000 - 0x30212fff  IAP armv7  <134f59ad5bb91bab6a5fe21b6f36dc8b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
0x302a2000 - 0x302cbfff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <54484a513761868149405df7fc29b5c0> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x302ce000 - 0x303edfff  Foundation armv7  <81d36041f04318cb51db5aafed9ce504> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x303ee000 - 0x304d4fff  CoreFoundation armv7  <01441e01f5141a50ee723362e59ca400> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x304dd000 - 0x305c6fff  GLEngine armv7  <305ddfcddb54d00acd8e2ca9005496c8> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/GLEngine.bundle/GLEngine
0x305fb000 - 0x30631fff  CoreLocation armv7  <e19b7aa132318fc90618a663bd576461> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x306a6000 - 0x306fffff  EventKit armv7  <037c4bb5e2529e6004d0e1f3d95a84cc> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x3078e000 - 0x307cdfff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <a7c117c92607a512823d307b8fdd0151> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x307f9000 - 0x30816fff  AppleAccount armv7  <e3833276f8877499c8dd76b3b3d88501> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x308c2000 - 0x308f5fff  QuickLook armv7  <8c54395accc7ffc84766ff3e9b24beb1> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x309e6000 - 0x309eefff  MobileBluetooth armv7  <6d6c62f52219d27be50f1d7c39a68dc6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileBluetooth.framework/MobileBluetooth
0x309ef000 - 0x30a22fff  AddressBook armv7  <7c87e0175c8649d6832419da8a1cfac1> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x30a23000 - 0x30a43fff  PrintKit armv7  <02a9c6f4173a0673c4637a3b570345cd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x30aa3000 - 0x30af3fff  GMM armv7  <2b63c1e1ce647e031a8a491e156f04d3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x30e64000 - 0x30eabfff  MessageUI armv7  <bb7d161bb6c699afb2e1744ece115ae8> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x30fd5000 - 0x31082fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <3f2df600942dc72aad312b3cc98ec479> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x31092000 - 0x311a3fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <138a43ab528bb428651e6aa7a2a7293c> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x311af000 - 0x312cffff  libmecabra.dylib armv7  <b2293b8acb00a14bace7520a63f39439> /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
0x312d0000 - 0x31312fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <96d3af505b9f2887e62c7e99c157733e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x31335000 - 0x3133ffff  ExternalAccessory armv7  <c00f372e7a4f31b4b333e8283d3167fc> /System/Library/Frameworks/ExternalAccessory.framework/ExternalAccessory
0x31340000 - 0x31373fff  iCalendar armv7  <6eb50e720d642f5ac510a36989b276b2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x31398000 - 0x31719fff  UIKit armv7  <de1cbd3219a74e4d41b30428f428e223> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x3174b000 - 0x31764fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <ee16b5cee12a8947c8e511ed51ae7fef> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x3177f000 - 0x317b5fff  CoreText armv7  <b9b5c21b2d2a28abc47842c78c026ddf> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x3180a000 - 0x318b3fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <b3d82f80a777cb1434052ea2d232e3df> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x318b4000 - 0x318e0fff  DataAccess armv7  <6b9b5235b449335ce5c66d53f32004cd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x31923000 - 0x31938fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <ea156820997ae9a2baf664d0f79f18d7> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x3194d000 - 0x3195dfff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <6767a1e2afbc86a1ec63dd784f5d3677> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x31971000 - 0x31980fff  Notes armv7  <7d7a3d10a349471cd2757a479d131b31> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x31981000 - 0x31a0afff  Message armv7  <69cb7cb1d1d7865fc04dc341544174b6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x31a0b000 - 0x31a9efff  ImageIO armv7  <5b5a294d4250eff866fdbf891b1e8b34> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x31b35000 - 0x31b3afff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <cec3f3271fc267c32c169ed03e312d63> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x31b3b000 - 0x31b64fff  ContentIndex armv7  <247576cb4f1ff8e92650ae3cb4973760> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x31cb5000 - 0x31d56fff  Celestial armv7  <b411f4662383ec24dbfbcde8f4c23d67> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x31d59000 - 0x31d61fff  libkxld.dylib armv7  <854e82fe66feef01e54c7c8a209851ac> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x31d62000 - 0x31dd1fff  ProofReader armv7  <d2e62a8ab7e1460c7f6de8913c703e6d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x31de0000 - 0x31ee7fff  CoreData armv7  <29b1ab7d339e42a6ff6923e54cf43e7b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x31ee8000 - 0x31ef4fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <0099670dccd99466653956bf918d667a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x31ff5000 - 0x32002fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <0f4e595e6eb2170aceb729f32b5de8c2> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x32003000 - 0x3229dfff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <2e77d87e96af938aacf0a6008e6fb89d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x322e7000 - 0x32316fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <3f982c11b5526fc39a92d585c60d8a90> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x323f9000 - 0x3242afff  VideoToolbox armv7  <bb7ff9014b1dabec2acce95d41f05b59> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x324ed000 - 0x3259cfff  WebKit armv7  <644a1c6120578f896bed7121307aa2af> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x3259f000 - 0x32643fff  IMGSGX535GLDriver armv7  <03ce082398774b1c545d08b64081d82e> /System/Library/Extensions/IMGSGX535GLDriver.bundle/IMGSGX535GLDriver
0x32644000 - 0x32687fff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <27ac7f05482a8aa9977150f34f9be6eb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x32692000 - 0x326a7fff  OpenAL armv7  <8ea22c729b71c6e7e19566b91a03afd2> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenAL.framework/OpenAL
0x326ae000 - 0x32764fff  MapKit armv7  <69921a6353270a6f77e0816d636812e8> /System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit
0x32765000 - 0x3276efff  WebBookmarks armv7  <9f1760206eaef20c605c5d98e45c823e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x3278a000 - 0x3279dfff  libmis.dylib armv7  <855aefc263c6c20e6cf8723ea36125a2> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x3279e000 - 0x327a6fff  MobileWiFi armv7  <b29d4c5e300ef81060e38f72bb583c02> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x327a7000 - 0x328e0fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <657b327f2ceee9f22f9474f2f9bddbe6> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x3290a000 - 0x32947fff  CoreMedia armv7  <4ea4d349e886206d1ecf5bae870f3f04> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x3297b000 - 0x32981fff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <7e279d3b6d1e1fd7dc8c8a883255fa17> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x32987000 - 0x329a8fff  MobileSync armv7  <cff20dfe818febca9f3232426d59a42d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x329af000 - 0x329b2fff  CertUI armv7  <5f37446c6b65a8c38ab6233c2e33da66> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x32a10000 - 0x32a12fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <1040629f37795146c9dcac8ab1a868fc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x32a68000 - 0x32a74fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <137b75e19b2450c234dec88d538798ff> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x32a88000 - 0x32bc5fff  MediaToolbox armv7  <a18bbcc41a38917fe0ae5e183d3f6b07> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x32c8f000 - 0x32c93fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <e861a330d14702f148ca5133dcbe954c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x32c94000 - 0x32ca6fff  VoiceServices armv7  <4cbd3ff5e9b756ac5f01dbd541eb6510> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VoiceServices.framework/VoiceServices
0x32ca7000 - 0x32ca9fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <8e6b0d9f642be06729ffdaaee97053b0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x32caa000 - 0x32cb5fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <fabaddbcbc8c02bab0261df9d78e0e25> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x32cba000 - 0x32cc9fff  MobileDeviceLink armv7  <8f2fc7e811bc57f7a09d7df81c329e1a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x32ccb000 - 0x32cd8fff  OpenGLES armv7  <a12565ffb5bb42e3019f1957cd4951d0> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x32cda000 - 0x32cdffff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <5f73c7138ee1cb7103a98aec99f9ed88> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x32d17000 - 0x32d1dfff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <5bbd9b3f5cfece328f80c403a8805ce9> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x32d1e000 - 0x32d69fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <251c5ac7380802a16e30d827c027c637> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x32d6a000 - 0x32e18fff  QuartzCore armv7  <83a8e5f0033369e437069c1e758fed83> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x32e19000 - 0x32f2ffff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <e7fbb2ac586567e574dc33d7bb5c4dc9> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x32f5b000 - 0x32f5efff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <a2af7147f5538d7669b14fa7b19b5a7c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x32f5f000 - 0x3301efff  CFNetwork armv7  <02fe0e30e54fffdcbbbd02e8cb812c3a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x33026000 - 0x33054fff  MIME armv7  <1989502ce4da514314647c6a0098d8e7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x330c3000 - 0x330fbfff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <374bd566263e8929c10d50d6a6a48a46> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x330fd000 - 0x33106fff  CoreVideo armv7  <2092d5deb6b234e04678b7c1878ccd81> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x3314b000 - 0x33195fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <53a6e7239c3908fa8c2915b65ff3b056> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x3319e000 - 0x331a1fff  IOSurface armv7  <deff02882166bf16d0765d68f0542cc8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x331a2000 - 0x331a4fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <3f0b58ea13d30f0cdb73f6ffe6d4e75c> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x331bd000 - 0x334cdfff  GeoServices armv7  <f6d9eba833e82b1a9a84b38ab7672012> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x334db000 - 0x33528fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <55038e5c1d4d0dbdd94295e8cad7a9a4> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x33890000 - 0x338c2fff  AppSupport armv7  <47c8055ac99f187174ca373b702ffa68> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x338c3000 - 0x338cafff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <2989ea7a5cad2cfe91bd632b041d0ff4> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x339bf000 - 0x339f9fff  IOKit armv7  <eb932cc42d60e55d9a4d0691bcc3d9ad> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x33a03000 - 0x33ac4fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <aaf5671a35f9ac20d5846703dafaf4c6> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x33aeb000 - 0x33aedfff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <e66758bcda6da5d7f9b54fa5c4de6da2> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x33aee000 - 0x33b43fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <9365fc6cae1bff737257e74faf3b1f26> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x33b4f000 - 0x33c3cfff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <c72b45f471df092dbd849081f7a3ef53> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x33ca7000 - 0x35620fff  TextInput armv7  <557601a7d93124fd5860606f294e900a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x35621000 - 0x35621fff  Accelerate armv7  <29dd5f17440bbb6e8e42e11b6fceda9a> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x3576d000 - 0x35770fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <3a385ed495379116abbe50bc8cd5a612> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x35836000 - 0x3591efff  libGLProgrammability.dylib armv7  <1f478a71783cd7eb4ae9ef6f2dcea803> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x35a46000 - 0x35a48fff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <30a5f1edcdb9ffe868a620199a4cbe12> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x35a49000 - 0x35a53fff  AccountSettings armv7  <19c79f81d5d55fe2e6b618fcdc28258e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x35a5e000 - 0x35a5ffff  CoreSurface armv7  <f7caaf43609cfe0e475dfe83790edb4d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x35a64000 - 0x35a7afff  EAP8021X armv7  <36659ec2b9def7b5798a05327e369247> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x35a7b000 - 0x36063fff  WebCore armv7  <d6bd9cf88ee82ab6b0e33e0ae1190772> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x36064000 - 0x36083fff  Bom armv7  <0f5fd6057bad5e1677869500d636821f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x3608d000 - 0x36094fff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <71372c95d4af7af787d0682a939e40ac> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x36097000 - 0x3612dfff  AddressBookUI armv7  <45665471fd70b0733b206d8166df74ef> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x3612e000 - 0x36140fff  PersistentConnection armv7  <cd2a699aa5036bdad0517603ba4db839> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x36141000 - 0x36178fff  Security armv7  <cd28e102950634ae7167ddee9c686d36> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
```

Comment: Perhaps you release some stuff in viewDidUnload that is not properly recreated in viewDidLoad? E.g. you create something in the init* method, throw it away when going into the background and don't recreate it properly?

Comment: check the didReceiveMemoryWarning method too. you have to reinitialize at viewDidLoad everything was deallocated at viewDidUnload or didReceiveMemoryWarning.

Comment: Check that [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581081/uialertview-crashing-on-undocumented-method), your alert view delegate might be deallocated.

Answer (score 0):

Try `autorelease` on `UIAlertView` or other UI elements that you displayed. May be you have forgotten to `retain` some of them.

Answer (score 0):

-[UIAlertView(Private) _popoutAnimationDidStop:finished:] issue appears when you are calling your alertview after you have released it. If you aren't using Automatic reference counting in your code, release your alertview only in your dealloc method like this:

```
-(void)dealloc {
    self.alertView.delegate = nil; //setting delegate to nil
    self.alertView = nil; //if you have defined alert as property
    //other release statements of your controller
    [super dealloc];
}
```